# Margin of caption different than text body in 2-column table (cas-dc)

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, captions, els-cas

I have the following problem:

[image]

I want the caption above the table to start flushed left and not with the space.  Here is the MWE copy paste from my project:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table*}[pos=t]

\caption{Observed results of the user study.}
\label{tab:Result_time}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllll}
\toprule
                                                         &                   & \textbf{P1} & \textbf{P2} & \textbf{P3} & \textbf{P4} & \textbf{P5} & \textbf{P6} & \textbf{P7} & \textbf{P8} & \textbf{P9} & \textbf{P10} & \textbf{P11} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Scenario 1}}} & Accuracy          & 100\%       & 50\%        & 100\%       & 0\%         & 100\%       & 100\%       & 100\%       & 0\%         & 100\%       & 50\%         & 100\%        \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                     & Time Taken        & 18:13       & 15:40       & 16:26       & 20:32       & 17:10       & 18:08       & 16:22       & 18:50       & 12:18       & 16:27        & 15:41        \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{}                                     & Number of queries & 18          & 10          & 11          & 15           & 7           & 12          & 16          & 22          & 12          & 10           & 15           \\ \midrule
\textbf{Scenario 2}                                      & Time Taken        & 7:35        & 8:39        & 10:20       & 10:41       & 9:47        & 14:28       & 12:24       & 18:28       & 8:29        & 9:11         & 8:24         \\ \midrule
\textbf{Scenario 3}                                      & Time Taken        & 6:21        & 4:50        & 5:42        & 7:18        & 4:30        & 4:52        & 4:27        & 5:15        & 5:04        & 6:12         & 5:48    
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

I've attempted to add `\captionsetup{justification=justified}` but to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`els-cas` initialises some variables (in this case the one which holds the width of the caption box) when loading the class, which happens before setting the page geometry, so the caption doesn't know that the text width changed (it's a<sub><sup><sub>nother</sub></sup></sub> bug).

When using two-column tables you need to explicitly say that the width is `\textwidth` using `\begin{table*}[width=\textwidth]`, but you can set this globally using this in your preamble:

```latex
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\FullWidth}{\textwidth}}
```

this will fix `els-cas`'s value for `\textwidth` (thanks egreg for pointing that out). Also, don't rescale a table. Period.

In your document:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\FullWidth}{\textwidth}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{table*}[pos=t,width=\textwidth]

\caption{Observed results of the user study.}
\label{tab:Result_time}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{13}{l}@{}}
\toprule
                                                         &                   & \textbf{P1} & \textbf{P2} & \textbf{P3} & \textbf{P4} & \textbf{P5} & \textbf{P6} & \textbf{P7} & \textbf{P8} & \textbf{P9} & \textbf{P10} & \textbf{P11} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Scenario 1}}} & Accuracy          & 100\%       & 50\%        & 100\%       & 0\%         & 100\%       & 100\%       & 100\%       & 0\%         & 100\%       & 50\%         & 100\%        \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{}                                     & Time Taken        & 18:13       & 15:40       & 16:26       & 20:32       & 17:10       & 18:08       & 16:22       & 18:50       & 12:18       & 16:27        & 15:41        \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}c}{}                                     & Number of queries & 18          & 10          & 11          & 15           & 7           & 12          & 16          & 22          & 12          & 10           & 15           \\ \midrule
\textbf{Scenario 2}                                      & Time Taken        & 7:35        & 8:39        & 10:20       & 10:41       & 9:47        & 14:28       & 12:24       & 18:28       & 8:29        & 9:11         & 8:24         \\ \midrule
\textbf{Scenario 3}                                      & Time Taken        & 6:21        & 4:50        & 5:42        & 7:18        & 4:30        & 4:52        & 4:27        & 5:15        & 5:04        & 6:12         & 5:48    
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works fine, however OP use one column document, so the same result it will obtain with `\begin{table}[pos=ht]` without specifying table width. About bug: it is good to know (+1).

Comment: @Zarko OP uses a double column document (the `dc` in `cas-dc` stands for “double column”). And about the bug, I'm not in the Elsevier team, so I can't confirm (though the behaviour is definitely bug-like :)

Comment: hm, In ma answer I add some "lipsum" text, and it appear as one column . That seem tha this document class hase more issues :-(

Comment: @Zarko It seems the class only sets up the page geometry when you do `\maketitle`. So yes, it has its fair share of issues...

Comment: Much better would be to issue `\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\FullWidth}{\textwidth}}` in the preamble. For the particular table, `\begin{tabular}{@{}*{13}{l}@{}}` avoids the need of resizing it.

Answer (score 2):

off-topic:

- don't use scale box for accommodate table into text width. Rather left to LaTeX to calculate the size of `\tabcolsep` with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` and if needed, in reduce font size used in table (in your case is not needed)
- since from MWE follows, that you have one column document, you can use simple `table` environment. At it you haven't reported problems:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{table}[pos=ht]
\caption{Observed results of the user study. \lipsum[66]}
\label{tab:Result_time}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lllllllllllll }
\toprule
    &   & \textbf{P1} & \textbf{P2} & \textbf{P3} & \textbf{P4} & \textbf{P5}
        & \textbf{P6} & \textbf{P7} & \textbf{P8} & \textbf{P9} & \textbf{P10}
        & \textbf{P11} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Scenario 1}}}
    & Accuracy
        & 100\%       & 50\%        & 100\%       & 0\%         & 100\%
        & 100\%       & 100\%       & 0\%         & 100\%       & 50\%
        & 100\%        \\
    & Time Taken
        & 18:13       & 15:40       & 16:26       & 20:32       & 17:10
        & 18:08       & 16:22       & 18:50       & 12:18       & 16:27
        & 15:41        \\
    & Number of queries
        & 18          & 10          & 11          & 15           & 7
        & 12          & 16          & 22          & 12          & 10
        & 15           \\ \midrule
\textbf{Scenario 2}
    & Time Taken
        & 7:35        & 8:39        & 10:20       & 10:41       & 9:47
        & 14:28       & 12:24       & 18:28       & 8:29        & 9:11
        & 8:24         \\ \midrule
\textbf{Scenario 3}
    & Time Taken
        & 6:21        & 4:50        & 5:42        & 7:18        & 4:30
        & 4:52        & 4:27        & 5:15        & 5:04        & 6:12
        & 5:48          \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

gives desired result:

[image]